# PowerShell script uploads files, operation times out on big files

Tags: powershell, office-365, time-out

I have a script that uploads files to Office 365 but when a big file is uploaded it fails and says operation has timed out.

Is there anyway of increasing this in PowerShell or some settings to allow my script to upload the bigger files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to know the exact cause of your error without actually seeing some code or error message.
One of the common reasons could be that you arent using the REST api and hence are only allowed a limited file size to upload.

The article [here](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/) explains how to upload using REST with Powershell. Also check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860864/powershell-http-post-file-upload-for-rest-api) question previously answered.

As a side note,
I suggest you do such operations using a console app that uses [PnP Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/OfficeDevPnP.Core) (Legend says it makes your life worth living. Ha ha).